# tmux で設定した画面分割の Prefix が効かない

Tags: tmux

macでtmuxを使いはじめました。

しかし `Ctrl + a` and `Shift + ¥`(|)

としてもPaneが分割されません、どうしてですか？

```
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix

# split panes using | and -
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
unbind '"'
unbind %

# force a reload of the config file
# reload config file (change file location to your the tmux.conf you want to use)
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

# quick pane cycling
unbind ^A
bind ^A select-pane -t :.+

# smart pane switching with awareness of vim splits
bind -n C-h run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-h) || tmux select-pane -L"
bind -n C-j run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-j) || tmux select-pane -D"
bind -n C-k run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-k) || tmux select-pane -U"
bind -n C-l run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-l) || tmux select-pane -R"
bind -n C-\ run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys 'C-\\') || tmux select-pane -l"

# resize pane
bind -n C-Down resize-pane -D 5
bind -n C-Up resize-pane -U 5
bind -n C-Right resize-pane -R 10
bind -n C-Left resize-pane -L 10

bind -n S-Down resize-pane -D 1
bind -n S-Up resize-pane -U 1
bind -n S-Right resize-pane -R 2
bind -n S-Left resize-pane -L 2
# tmux status bar color
set-option -g status-keys "emacs"
set -g status-left-length 50
set -g status-right " Show Terminal #(date '+%a, %b %d - %I:%M') "

bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"

set -g renumber-windows on

bind-key b break-pane -d
bind-key C-j choose-tree

# Use vim keybindings in copy mode
setw -g mode-keys vi

# Setup 'v' to begin selection as in Vim
bind-key -t vi-copy v begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"

# Update default binding of `Enter` to also use copy-pipe
unbind -t vi-copy Enter
bind-key -t vi-copy Enter copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

Answer (score 1):

LinuxMint19.2(Ubuntu18.04LTSと同等)で普通に入るtmux2.6で.tmux.confを入れ替えて試しましたが、
「Ctrl+a」「|」の順番でキー入力したら、ペインが追加された結果としてターミナルが左右に分割されました。

> しかし Ctr + a and Shift + ¥(|)

これはどういうキー入力をするのか、ちょっとわからなかったのですが、
「Ctrl+a」「|」の順番でキー入力するとどうなりますか？

Comment: `Ctrl+a` これは同時押し、ということですよね？|と順番に打っても反応しません、。、。。。。

Comment: 「Ctrl+a」「-」などの他のキーバインドは動作するけど、「Ctrl+a」「|」だけが動作しないということでしょうか？

Comment: 「Ctrl+a」「?」でキーバインドの一覧が表示されると思うのですが、そこで出る内容は意図した通りになってますか？

Comment: いえ、Paneの変更以外ダメです、、、Ctrl+aは同時押しであってますよね？

Comment: Ctrl+aは同時押しです。細かく言うとCtrlキーを少し先に押しながらaキーを押します

Comment: 「Paneの変更以外ダメです」について、もうちょっと細かく現在の状況を説明することは出来ますか？(質問文からは「Ctrl+a」「|」だけが使えなくて、その他のキーは意図通りに使えていると解釈してました。)

Comment: えっと、かなり初心者なので正確に伝えられるか不安ですが、Ctr+hとかでPaneの移動はできます。ideというネットに落ちてあったコマンドを自作してPaneを4分割しています

Comment: しかし、Ctr+aを同時押し下のち、例えば|を押してもPaneが分割されません。Ctr+aののち、-もダメです。

Comment: tmux.confにあるその他のコマンドはコピペなので自分はよく分かっていないです、、すいません

Comment: なるほど…つまり…。bind-keyに「-n」オプションを付けているものは動作している。「-n」オプションはプレフィックスキー(今回の場合「Ctrl+a」)を付けずに使うキーバインド指定です。「-n」オプションがついていないbind-keyが動作していない。という状態でしょうか？わかる範囲で確認してみてください。

Comment: 推測ですが…、「Ctrl+a」が何か別のアプリケーションで解釈されて無効になってるとかかもしれないですね。プレフィックスキーを「Ctrl+a」以外のキーにしてみて動作するか確認してみてください。tmuxのデフォルトは「Ctrl+b」なのでそれにしてみるとか。

Comment: キーバインドを変更するとなぜかできました！！！感謝します！！本当にありがとうです